# How to derive the formula for the amount?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

*Compounded half-yearly:*

Amount after half year = $P(1+\frac {R/2}{100})^{2n}$

---

How can we derive this formula?

Comment: Hint: By what factor does "the amount" change every half-year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the half-yearly compound interest rate be $I$, in percent.

After the first half year, the amount is $P+\frac I{100}P=(1+\frac I{100})P$.

After the second half year, $(1+\frac I{100})P+\frac I{100}(1+\frac I{100})P=(1+\frac I{100})^2P$, and the general pattern is obvious.

---

Now we have a little technicality, as what is given is a yearly interest rate, $R$, which is a *simple* rate instead of a *compound* one. That means that if after a year you get $R\%$, after a half year you get $\frac R2\%$, and this is our $I$.

Note that mathematician's logic would be that $R$ also be a compound rate, and we should have $(1+\frac I{100})^2=1+\frac R{100}$ or $I=100(\sqrt{1+\frac R{100}}-1)$, but this is not the way it is.

Comment: Shouldn't it be P $+ \frac {0.5IP}{100}$ as the time period is 0.5 years?

Comment: @Cognoscenti: grrrr, read the explanations !

Comment: Please tell me.

Comment: @Cognoscenti: I did.

Comment: I didn't understand.

Comment: Could you please tell me?

Comment: Why is it not $\frac {0.5PI}{100}$?

Comment: Oh! It's the first half-year.